# Remote form in rails with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am unable to do the following thing:

In a page I have a form; When I submit it, I want to insert a record in the database, and hide that form, **without** reloading the page.

The form is:

```
<div class="slide-out-div">
    <% form_for @post, :url=>'/posts/create', :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
        <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

in *application.js* I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_post").submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr("action");
        var cont = form["content"].value;
        var formData = form.serialize(); 
        $.post(url, formData, function(html) { 
            alert('Message sent');
            $(".slide-out-div").hide('fast');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

in *posts_controller.rb* :

```
def create
    if !params[:post][:content].nil? and params[:post][:content].length>0
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        @post.save
    end
end
```

The problem is that after the record is inserted, the alert is not shown, and the page *'/posts/create'* is loaded (it's a blank page, because I didn't write anything in `create.rb`) I cannot use redirect_to, because I don't know what is the current page (the form will be on every page of the site). Anyway, I don't want to reload the page. (`return false` in submit() should not leave the page, but it does.) What could be the problem?

P.S. I can't use Rails 3, where I saw that there is a remote_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_post").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); <-- prevent the default form submission
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr("action");
        var cont = form.find("name='post\\[content\\]'").val();
        var formData = form.serialize(); 
        $.post(url, formData, function(html) { 
            alert('Message sent');
            $(".slide-out-div").hide('fast');
        });           
    });
});
```

Comment: If I add `e.preventDefault();`, nothing happens when I press submit.

Comment: can you check in the firebug if the `post` is made when you `preventDefault` behaviour of the `submit`

Comment: How do I do that? If I add an `alert()` after `preventDefault()`, the alert is shown. But I don't know if it gets further. The new record is not inserted.

Comment: install the firebug plugin for mozilla firefox, chrome has built in developer tools in which you can see the ajax requests being made under the network tab, hit `f12` in chrome to bring up the developer tools...http://getfirebug.com/..........as far as i can tell the `$.post` is not working reasons can be many but without debugging it not possible to tell.

Comment: I have an error at `form["content"].value`. If I remove `.value`, it works.

Comment: But how can I test if `cont` is empty or not? On SO I found `if (cont === "")` and `if(cont)`, but it does not work in this case.

Comment: i am not familiar with the rails syntax can you post the html that `<%= f.text_area :content %>` line spits out i think its like name of the textarea ?? if that is the case you can try `var cont = form.find("textarea[name='content']").val();`

Comment: `<textarea name="post[content]" id="post_content"></textarea>`

Comment: Now it's so clear! The javascript never read that field ok, but in rails, the reading from 'content' was ok. Because the rails part was working, I thought the value was read there too.

Comment: if you know the idea then you can select by `id` like `var cont = form.find("post_content").val();` or if you have to select by name you can do it like `var cont = form.find('[name="post\\[content\\]"]').val();`